# Creating thumbnails of Overlayed images in jquery

Tags: jquery, overlay

I am tying to address a problem which we are facing in creating Thumbnails of the overlayed images.

The problem is
I have database of samller images and a Static image. User will select few smaller images which needs to overlayed on the static image. User also selects the position over the static image where the smaller images needs to overlayed. But as of now we are not creating a seperate image of newly created overlayed image, but we are storing the images and co-ordinate information. when user logs back, we want to show thumbnail view of the overlayed image[though we dont store overlayed image seperately, but we have a his selected image, co-ordinates for overlaying images, etc stored in db].
Are there any jquery plugin avaialable or any other pointer to achieve the same?

Rgds,
Sandep

Comment: What code do you already have? jsFiddle perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to produce a stored, combined image of the static one and smaller ones; you will have to process it in the back-end. If you are using PHP, the GD2 library are available.

If your audience is HTML5 compatible, you can also use the HTML5 canvas to overlay the images, then output the raw-pixel-data to an JS Image() object, and then display that on the page.